# Riemannian covering space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces

Suppose $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a connected, oriented and complete smooth Riemannian manifold with mean curvature $H\geq 0$. (We may even suppose $M$ is the graph of a smooth function).

Do we know $M$ admits a Universal covering with the following properties:

-The universal covering has non-negative mean curvature.

-If the second fundamental form on the Universal covering space is uniformly bounded, it is uniformly bounded on $M$ by the same constant.

Comment: The question makes no sense as stated: talking about non-intrinsic curvatures of $X$ requires embedding $X$ into some space, and you don't have any embedding here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have added necessary conditions.

Comment: You're misunderstanding: it's obviously implied that $M$ is already embedded into $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ when you wrote $M\subseteq \Bbb R^{n+1}$ (the embedding being the inclusion mapping). I'm talking about $X$, not $M$.

Comment: Good question. I am considering $X$ to be the unique (up to diffeomorphism) covering space of $M$. Do we not know there exist a covering space of $M$ which is necessarily embedded in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$? I have read arguments for minimal surfaces for instance, and the authors (Colding, Minicozzi) states that a minimal surface admits a universal cover, which is again a minimal surface in the same ambient space.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318777/embedding-covers-of-manifolds  shows that there are submanifolds of Euclidean space which have covers which can't be embedded in the same Euclidean space.  I don't know if this can happen for minimal surfaces in Euclidean space, though.

Comment: Have you tried the simplest examples with $n=2$? If so, please edit your post to enlighten us.

Comment: There's no _unique_ covering space. Did you mean the universal cover?

Comment: Yes, Universal covering. Just as in the post.